# create new lvm from existing lvm

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I already have one lvm of 20gb but I want only 5gb lvm for PostgreSQL installation.I googled a lot but I am not able to find how to create new lvm if I have existing one.Below is the output of `cfdisk`.

[image]

Below is the out put of `lsblk`

[image]

below is output of `lvdisplay`
[image]

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsblk`?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along Posted.

Comment: Okay, now `lvdisplay`

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along posted

Comment: [Do not post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 0):

Logical volumes are created with lvcreate. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvcreate.8.html

Here's an example:

```
lvcreate -ay -L 5G --name lv_postgres vg_cumulocitytest1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to find how to create new lvm if I have existing one

When you say "new lvm" you should be clear what you're talking about: LVM has physical volumes (PVs), volume groups (VGs), and logical volumes (LVs). It sort of sounds like you want to create a new LV for Postgres' use.

It seems like your problem is not so much creating a new LV, but that, according to the images you posted (post **text** next time!!) your two existing LVs already occupy the entire amount of available space in your single volume group.

You may have created your two LVs (root and swap) at installation time to completely occupy all of the available space. In the future, I recommend against doing that. It's really easy to grow the size of an LV, so err on the side of creating your root filesystem smaller, so you have spare space in the VG. (Yes, with *some* filesystem types it's also not too difficult to shrink an existing LV to make room, but it's a little less easy and inherently more dangerous.) If nothing else, the spare space in the VG can be used for LVM snapshots (useful for backups).

Now that you *do* already have no empty space in your VG though, you'll have to reduce the size of one of your LVs. Probably the root filesystem since it's the larger one. This depends on what kind of filesystem is on that LV. For some types of filesystems (xfs) it's not possible to shrink them. For others it is. You can easily find documentation on how to do that. Just make sure you shrink the filesystem first, then shrink the LV to match (for growing, you do it in the opposite order).